# Split/duplicate line, like a reverse group_concat

Tags: regex, string, bash, text, data-manipulation

I want to split/duplicate lines (split some part, and copy the rest), quite like reverse `group_concat` in MySQL.

Input is as follows (there are over 1M lines total):

```
2016-07-18 08:55:09,www.rozklad-pkp.pl,0.575,160x600;120x600,standard
2016-07-18 08:55:09,rozklad-pkp.pl,0.575,320x50;468x60;320x100;750x200;300x75,mobile
2016-07-18 08:55:09,wpolityce.pl,0.87,300x75;300x250;320x100;300x50;320x50,mobile
```

For example from 2nd line I want to get:

```
2016-07-18 08:55:09,rozklad-pkp.pl,0.575,320x50,mobile
2016-07-18 08:55:09,rozklad-pkp.pl,0.575,468x60,mobile
2016-07-18 08:55:09,rozklad-pkp.pl,0.575,320x100,mobile
2016-07-18 08:55:09,rozklad-pkp.pl,0.575,750x200,mobile
2016-07-18 08:55:09,rozklad-pkp.pl,0.575,300x75,mobile
```

I don't know how to get there, especially if the amount of lines I want to split a single line varies.

The concept is too abstract for me, I don't know how to "grasp" it properly.

I thought about "mapping" lines, splitting it into separate parts (left part, the part to be split and the right part), grep'ing the count of semicolons, splitting and copying it back together; but it is quite complicated for me, and I think there must be other, simplier way.

I can use grep, sed, awk, Perl etc (bash in general), or SQLite.

Comment: For all the lines, where there are many sizes listed (separated by semicolons).
edit: so, example line 1 splitted into 2; line 2 into 5 (as shown), and line 3 into 5 etc.

Comment: I don't want to remove anything, just split/duplicate if there are many sizes (those are sizes of ad banners, in fact). Some lines will not contain semicolons, in that case there are good as there are now. Lines containing semicolons are to be split into as many new lines (duplicating left and right; and cutting those values between, 1 per line) as there are values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following `awk` script:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{split($4,a,";"); for(i in a) {$4=a[i];print}}' file
```

which will be duplicate the lines based on the content of the 4th field of each line.

Comment: Same in perl `perl -F, -ane 'for(split/;/,$F[3]){$F[3]=$_;print join(",",@F)}' file`